# FindMinimum from DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, fitting

I need to find the values of x, y that correspond to the minimum value of the function (in this example it is -1.0, the black area).
Code example:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear if you have the functions and you want to find the minimum, or if you only have an image, and you want to find the minimum from the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FindMinimum[Sin[x] Sin[y], {{x, #[[1]]}, {y, #[[2]]}}] & /@ {{-2, 
   2}, {2, -2}}

(* {{-1., {x -> -1.5708, y -> 1.5708}}, {-1., {x -> 1.5708, 
   y -> -1.5708}}} *)
```

Or for exact results,

```
Minimize[{Sin[x] Sin[y], 0 <= x <= 4, -3 <= y <= 3}, {x, y}]

(* {-1, {x -> π/2, y -> -(π/2)}} *)

Minimize[{Sin[x] Sin[y], -4 <= x <= 0, -3 <= y <= 3}, {x, y}]

(* {-1, {x -> -(π/2), y -> π/2}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = Sin[x] Sin[y];
deq = Grad[eq, {x, y}];
roots = {x, y} /. NSolve[{deq == 0, -4 <= x <= 4, -3 <= y <= 3}, {x, y}]
{{0, 0}, {-3.14159, 0}, {-1.5708, -1.5708}, {-1.5708, 
  1.5708}, {1.5708, -1.5708}, {1.5708, 1.5708}, {3.14159, 0}}

hesse[x_, y_] = D[eq, {{x, y}, 2}] /. Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ roots;
{PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hesse[x, y], NegativeDefiniteMatrixQ /@ hesse[x, y]} // Column
{False, False, False, True, True, False, False},
{False, False, True, False, False, True, False}

 eq /. Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ roots
{0, 0., 1., -1., -1., 1., 0.}
```

The 4th and 5th zeros are the searched minima.